# How to wrap errors and make them checkable?

Tags: go, error-handling

I'm implementing a server that uses TCP. The read function has the following signature

```golang
func ReadNext() (Message, error)
```

The function can fail for two reasons:

1. Connection is lost
2. Parsing error

My first reflex is to wrap the error with `fmt.Errorf()`. However I want to offer the consumer of that package the ability to check and dispatch depending on the fail reason, so using the builtin wrapping do not offer that option as far as I understand.

I read [Don’t just check errors, handle them gracefully](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully) and found that basically he advocate for wrapping with custom error type and use type asserting on a custom interface. I find that quite verbose and require a lot of extra code. Plus, I don't see behaviour related to my error types would make it cleaner:

```
type ParseError interface {
  IsParseError() bool
}

type NetworkError interface {
  IsNetworkError() bool
}
```

I basically see three options:

- Do not wrap and return sentinelle error
- Wrap with custom error type and do type comparison
- Dave Cheney style: wrap with custom error type and assert against interface that describe the behaviour.

I find no solution particularly good or elegant. Any suggestion?

Comment: Good question. But there's no single best answer. Unfortunately, this is somewhat opinionated.

Comment: Updated my answer with sample code. My opinion is to use consts over interface to minimize casts and improve readability.

Answer (score 2):

Errors are complicated because, well, errors simply *are* complicated.

Dave Cheney's blog post includes this statement:

> I have concluded that there is no single way to handle errors.

which I thoroughly agree with.  Consider something simple like "reading data from a file".  This can fail.  But *why* can it fail, and is there something you can do about those failures?

Here are some reasons it could fail.  This is not meant to be a full list of the entire universe of possible reasons, just *some* of them:

1. Perhaps the file doesn't exist.  It should, but just doesn't.

   There is probably nothing you can do about this.
2. Perhaps the file does exist, but you don't have permissions to access it.  You should, but you just don't.

   There is probably nothing you can do about this *unless* you have administrator access, in which case, you can give yourself permission and proceed.
3. Perhaps the file exists and you have permission to access it, but the data have become corrupt.

   There is probably nothing you can do about this, but if the system is self-healing (such systems exist) this might be temporary.
4. Perhaps the file is briefly inaccessible because it's on a network and the network is partitioned.

   This is similar to case 3: waiting and retrying might fix the problem (in fact it's probably *more* likely than in case 3).

> ... [he suggests] wrapping with custom error type and use type asserting on a custom interface. I find that quite verbose and require a lot of extra code.

It does indeed.  It also requires cooperation from whoever *generates* the error in the first place, so that you can make these kinds of fine distinctions.  That's because you are dealing with real hardware and software systems, which are really complicated.

This is not very satisfying, but it's true.  Fortunately, for a lot of software, a lot of error cases can be lumped into "not my problem": the first two examples of being unable to open and read some file above (doesn't exist or permission denied) can be put in this group.  If you're writing a file-listing utility or something along those lines, this is probably fine.  If you're writing code to run a pacemaker, stopping with an error message ("fatal: can't report heart rate") might well be, er, fatal.  You'll need to consider context.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap an error say `err` with `fmt.Errorf`, you can check the error by `errors.Is`

Example:

```golang
    var ExpectedError = errors.New("This is an error")
    err := fmt.Errorf("I am now wrapping %w ",ExpectedError)
    fmt.Println("Checking error", errors.Is(err, ExpectedError))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/wtOeopA-f5B

Comment: I understand, however I do not control the underlying error (polymorphic/interface dependency), so that does not work in my case I think.

Comment: @noyo87 it still works, the `ExpectedError` here is just an example, it could be any `error` value. Check the docs for more info.

Answer (score -3):

Errors provide guard to the code that should not run AND way to handle post failure stategy.

Learnings from Swift & Rust applied in idiomatic go style:

At application level I would like to have all the errors at one place so that I know what errors this application handles.

All the unit tests and  application behavior regarding errors will be based on error types and error variables that my application defines.
For this I will have to write conversion from lib errors to AppErrors and use them wherever the error is first checked by the application.

So if any of the lib changes or is replaced by equivalent lib then just need to change the conversions of errors (adapting). Rest of the application error handling strategy remains as is and tested.

Error types implementing interface or we just use error type check/switch is secondary to above.

**Here is a sample of the approach. I prefer using consts in order to minimize casts. I believe that will be more faster and readable.**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type ErrorType int

const (
    ReaderEndError ErrorType = iota + 1
    ResourceNotFoundError
)

type AppError struct {
    ErrType ErrorType
    s       string
    error
}

func (ae AppError) Error() string {
    return ae.s
}

func (ae *AppError) GetType() ErrorType {
    return ae.ErrType
}

func main() {

    _, err := readData("notexists")
    if err != nil {
        if ae, ok := err.(AppError); ok {
            //should use switch case in actual startegy
            if ae.ErrType == ResourceNotFoundError {
                if ae.error != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Inner wrapped details (use for logging)", ae.error)
                }

                fmt.Println("handle ResourceNotFoundError here")
            }
        }
    }
}

//sample func
func readData(file string) (*string, error) {
    _, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        //switch case here actually
        e, _ := err.(*os.PathError)
        //actually should have many helper conversion functions to do below conversions
        return nil, AppError{ResourceNotFoundError, "Not found", e}
    }

    //assume read data
    data := string("data")
    return &data, nil
}
```